# How to change part of the string in current buffer path

Tags: vim

I'm using the following line in `_vimrc` to launch current buffer in firefox in windows

```
abbrev ff :! start firefox %:p<cr>
```

There are two problems:

1) When I do `:ff` and there are spaces in path, then the buffers are launched in separate tabs.

2) Also, I want to replace `C:/wamp/www` in `%p` to `http://localhost/` when opening in firefox, so that I don't have to change it manually, when working with local server.

How to achieve this?

**UPDATE: 
solution:**

I've Removed `shellescape()` and it works perfectly in windows. I use the following code in vimrc now.

```
abbrev ff :exec '! start firefox 'substitute(expand('%:p'), '^C:/wamp/www/','http://localhost/','')<CR>
```

Thanks El Isra for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

`abbrev ff :exec '! start firefox '.shellescape(substitute(expand('%:p'), '^C:/wamp/www/','http://localhost/',''))<CR>`

Comment: Now, the address bar shows both, File path and Localhost path

Comment: For Eg: file:///C:/wamp/www/OOP/%27http://localhost/OOP/date.php%27

This is how date.php in wamp directory shows up in address bar

Comment: I don't work with Windows, but it seems to me that `start` is using the URL as a file path and adds the current directory, I have no idea about how to by-pass that.

Comment: I've Removoed `shellescape()` and it works perfectly now. Thanks a ton.